# Evidence for $Q^{\operatorname{solv}}$ being pseudo-algebraically-closed

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, fields, global-fields

This is a follow-up to the following answer:

[Solvable class field theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4379/solvable-class-field-theory/4386#4386)

in which it is stated as a "folklore" conjecture that the maximal solvable extension of Q is pseudo algebraically closed (this means, in particular, any geometrically connected variety over Q has a point over a solvable extension).

I am curious what evidence there is to support such a conjecture.

In addition, what can be said for the analogous statement for global function fields?

Comment: Pete's answer in the linked thread has at least the start of an answer to this question, so potential answerers should read that to avoid duplication.

Also:  I think "Galois theory of fields" people tend to believe this conjecture more than "rational points on varieties" people, to the extent that those aren't the same people. 

Comment: JSE is correct on both counts.  If anyone cares, I didn't say that I believed in the conjecture myself, just that it would be nice if it were true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So far as I know, there is no compelling evidence to support this conjecture.  (And some leading arithmetic geometers think it is false.)  Rather, there are some very interesting consequences of this conjecture, e.g. a solution of the Inverse Galois Problem over Q^{solv}: in other words, for any finite group G, there exists a tower of radical extensions

K_0 = Q, K_1 = K_0(a_0^{1/n_0}) < K_2 = K_1(a_1^{1/n_1}) < ... <= K_n

and a Galois extension L/K_n with Galois group isomorphic to G.  It also shows that geometrically irreducible algebraic varieties "acquire rational points" in a very different way from irreducible zero-dimensional varieties (which have a unique minimal 
splitting field which need not be solvable).

Of course, interesting things which follow from a conjecture are, if anything, evidence *against* the truth of the conjecture, although they support the claim that the *question* is interesting.

There is one impressive result towards this conjecture, namely the Ciperiani-Wiles theorem: let C_{/Q} be a genus one curve with points everywhere locally and semistable Jacobian elliptic curve E.  Then C(Q^{solv}) is nonempty.

On the negative side, there is a paper of Ambrus Pal which constructs, for each sufficiently large integer g, a curve C of genus g over a field K which does not admit any points over the maximal solvable extension of K.  (Here K is not a number field.)

On the other hand, as far as I know, it is still open to find an absolutely irreducible variety V/Q which fails to have rational points over the maximal *metabelian extension* of Q, i.e., over (Q^{ab})^{ab}.  For some thoughts about this, see

http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/abeliantalk.pdf

ADDENDUM:

I forgot to address the last part of the question: what about global function fields?

As I alluded to above, there are counterexamples over the function field of a sufficiently complicated ground field, like Q. Of course you mean a finite extension of F_q(T), in which case I think absolutely nothing is known. In particular, I believe the analogue of Ciperiani-Wiles is open here, and might not be a straightforward adaptation, since C-W uses results on the modularity of elliptic curves. This could make a nice thesis problem...but I would talk to Mirela Ciperiani before doing any serious work on it.

Answer (score 4):

I'll respond to this question with another question.  Given a curve C/Q, there is a solvable extension K/Q such that C/K has local points everywhere.  (At least I think this is is the case; it requires some kind of argument on approximating local solvable extensions by global ones, which I've seen done before.) Some people believe that the Brauer-Manin obstruction is the only obstruction to the Hasse principle for curves.  If that were the case, would it say anything about your question?

Comment: (At least I think...): Yes. it follows using (i) that every finite extension of a local field is solvable, and (ii) the observation that local extensions of the form X^n - a can be approximated by global extensions of that form (Krasner's Lemma).

The assumption about Brauer-Manin would give you that once you've made a solvable extension to get points everywhere locally, then either you have a global point or you have a Brauer obstruction.  Are you suggesting that you could then kill the Brauer obstruction by making a further solvable extension?  That's interesting...